# Calling non-static method with call_user_func_array in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to call an object's non-static method with call_user_func_array but I'm not understanding how to formulate the callback. I've found a lot of similar examples online but nothing quite like what I'm running into.

```
class DBCommand {
    private $db; // The DBConnection object

    function __construct() {
        $db = new DBConnection();
    }

    function callMethod($method, $arguments) {
        // This line gives me the error:
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->db, "$method"), $arguments);
    }
}
?>
```

Calling callMethod with the name of a DBConnection method and its proper arguments gives me this

```
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid 
callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object
```

And because of this, callMethod returns null.

Comment: `$this->db = new DBConnection();` in constructor. Currently you assign a connection object to just a local variable, not to an object field.

Comment: Side note, you don't need to quote the variable. Just `$method` will work.

Comment: @csstudent you will run into an infinite recursion when you instantiate `DBConnection`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the notation `[$objectHandle, "methodName"]` to dynamically call a non-static method:

```
call_user_func_array([$this,$method], $arguments);
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/Io2Fl)

Comment: The question asks about **non** static methods

Comment: @BeetleJuice Actually there's no infinite recursion. DBCommand != DBConnection

Comment: My bad I misread OP class's name as `DBConnection` when it's `DBCommand`. I've removed that note from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to handle that in a controller method calling in a **MVC** structure

What worked for me was creating a new instance of the class that the desired method to call exists in and passing that instance instead of calling directly from the parent class:

> ```
>    $controller = new $controller(); 
>    call_user_func_array([$controller, $this->method], $this->params);
> ```

As it will produce a Fatal Error if the method being called is **non-static** :

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1
> ($callback) must be a valid callback, non-static method
> $ClassController::desiredMethod() cannot be called statically

Try to work with static methods or use this approach *(new-instance)* for whoever faces a similar problem!